# When do the Kodomo no Jikan OVA side stories take place?

Tags: kodomo-no-jikan

Kodomo no Jikan has a 3-episode OVA released from 2007 to 2011. The episodes are side-stories which are not directly related to the plot, but I think they are still based on the manga chapters. As such, they should fall somewhere in the story.

Relative to the anime, where do these 3 episodes fall?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Kodomo_no_Jikan_episodes) lists the 3 OVA episodes in question as follows:

- **Yasumi Jikan '~Anata ga Watashi ni Kureta Mono~'** is between the 4th and 5th episodes of the 1st season.
- **Kuro-chan to Shiro-chan** occurs between the 1st and 2nd episodes of the 2nd season (which is a 3-episode OVA season)
- **Kodomo no Natsu Jikan** takes place after the end of the second season.

Answer (score 2):

Kodomo no Jikan has 7 OVA episodes.

- **Kodomo no Jikan: Rin no Gakkyuu Nisshi** is a summery episode of the
  TV series. This OVA episode was released in 2008.
- **Kodomo no Jikan: Yasumi Jikan - Anata ga Watashi ni Kureta Mono** is
  a side story of the TV series. This episode was released 2007 during
  the original TV series.
- **Kodomo no Jikan: Ni Gakki** are 3 episodes and are kind of a sequel,
  because they play after the TV series. This OVA series were released
  in 2009.
- **Kodomo no Jikan: Kuro-chan to Shiro-chan** is kind of a side story of
  'Kodomo no Jikan: Ni Gakki'. This OVA episode was released in 2009.
- **Kodomo no Jikan: Kodomo no Natsu Jikan** is one episode and is kind
  of a sequel of 'Kodomo no Jikan: Ni Gakki'. This OVA episode was
  released in 2011.

Comment: I'm specifically asking about where Anata ga Watashi ni Kureta Mono, Kuro-chan to Shiro-chan, and Kodomo no Natsu Jikan fall chronologically within the story. Your answer covers some of that (I think you've covered Kodomo no Natsu Jikan completely), but if possible I'd like episode numbers for what episodes of the main series or Ni Gakki the other two fall between.